# Генерация случайных слов

Tags: javascript

Не знаю как это реализовать.

Есть код который должен выводить подряд 3 случайных слова без повторений. Он работает, но как сделать чтобы впереди слова добавлялось постоянное описание, например:

1 серый: медведь
2 белый: заяц
3 бурый: лиса

Нужно чтобы менялись только названия животных, список цветов всегда одинаковый. Здесь для примера 5 слов, но их количество может быть разным. `

Если не трудно, можно объяснить подробнее?

```js
'use strict';

var numWords = 3, 
words = ["волк ","лиса ","заяц ","медведь ","ежик "];

var rand = function(from, to) { 
    var n = Math.floor((to - from + 1) * (Math.random() %100)); 
    return (from + n); 
} 
     
var newWords = words; 
var loops = (words.length - numWords); 
     
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) { 
    newWords.splice(rand(0, words.length - 1), 1); 
} 

console.log(newWords.join(''));
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

К примеру можно так:

```js
    function randAccess(arr){
      return arr.splice([Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)],1)
    }
    
    var color = ["белый","желтый","синий","красный","фиолетовый"];
    var animal = ["заяц","волк","кит","кот","собака"];
    
    color.forEach(function(item, index){
        console.log(index + " " + item + ":" + randAccess(animal));
    })
```

Вам надо завести два массива, один с цветами и второй с животными. Далее в цикле к каждому цвету выбирать животное, при этом так, что бы животные не повторялись. Для этого можно элемент при выборе удалять из массива с помощью `splice`.